# Is there a way to disable a language from being switched to, but keep it in WIndows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, language-bar

I want to have an ability to write Japanese on my computer, but as I don't use it very often, I spend time when I want to switch to other languages I use. Is there a way to install Japanese, use keyboard and stroking, but remove it from language bar and Alt+Shift switching&

Comment: Do you have more than two languages in all ?

Comment: No, that's not possible. Can you tell us why you want to hide it? Maybe we can give you an alternative solution? For example, you can have different languages and different keyboard layouts. Switching between languages can be done with alt-shift, while switching between keyboard layouts can be done with ctrl-shift. If you move japanese to a different keyboard layout, it should be removed from the list with other languages.

Comment: @harrymc yeah, three in total with japanese

Comment: @LPChip I want to do it because it is bothersome to switch between three languages all the time, when I only need two, but I still want to keep the japanese to use pen and typing with hiragana/katakana

Comment: Why don't you choose the simpler solution of assigning each language a keyboard shortcut and switching directly and not via Alt+Shift?